# Get values in every row with specific column name's using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to read .xlsx file to get values in every row with specific column name's and keep them into string array.

```html
Sample data from file.xlsx

A   B   C
A123 B123 C123
A456 B456 C456
A789 B789 C789
A999
```

```html
This is the code that try to get values from column A, but it's not get the correct result.

InputStream is = file.getInputstream();
int rowTotal = 0;
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
rowTotal = sheet.getLastRowNum();

if((rowTotal > 0) || (sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() > 0)) {
 rowTotal++; 
 log.debug("rowTotal : "+rowTotal);    
 
 int colNum = -1;
 for(int i = 0; i <= rowTotal; i++) {
  if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals("A")) 
         colNum = i;
  row = sheet.getRow(i+1);
  XSSFCell cellA = row.getCell(colNum);
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
  String valueA = formatter.formatCellValue(cellA);
  log.debug("Data from col A : "+valueA);
       
  }
 }
}
```

```html
The result from log are..
rowTotal : 5
Data from col A : A123
Data from col A : A456
Data from col A : A789

Why it's not print "A999" ?
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Post the code that you've got and where it doesn't work, and we can help. However, StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, you need to have started the coding!

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for suggestion, and now i already add the code that i'm try to do.